# Points from polygon with buffer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, arcgis-10.5

How can I get points from polygon considering a buffer zone where within that buffer only one point will be generated. I have a few polygons for suitable locations. Now I want to make points from them, but I also need to consider at least 500m distance from one point to another. I have tried to densify and vertices to points, generate points along line but none of these are giving expected outcome.

[image]

Comment: These red marked polygons are my suitable locations. Now I want points in these area considering a 500m buffer/interval.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Please do not comment on your own Question. Any clarifications should be made within the body of the question. We need to know what you've tried, and what error or invalid output you received. If you use Python, we need the relevant code snippet. Make sure you include the exact version of ArcGIS and your license level in the question body.